# Why NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, beancreationexception

In this small app, I have used `@Autowired` annotation along with `@Qualifier` annotation to config the dependencies, but still an exception is thrown as mentioned below.

**Pizaa class**

```
public class Pizza {

    private Address deliverydest;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ForPizza")
    public void setDeliverydest(Address deliverydest) {
        this.deliverydest = deliverydest;
    }
}
```

**Spring Context Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="pizza" class="com.test.Shopping.Pizza" />

    <bean id="Cust1Address" class="com.test.Shopping.Address" />

    <bean id="dest1" class="com.test.Shopping.Address" >
        <qualifier value="ForPizza" />
        <property name="buildingno" value="flat1/door2" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

The exception thrown is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pizza': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.test.Shopping.Pizza.setDeliverydest(com.test.Shopping.Address); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.Shopping.Address] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: Cust1Address,dest1

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.test.Shopping.Pizza.setDeliverydest(com.test.Shopping.Address); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.Shopping.Address] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: Cust1Address,dest1

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.Shopping.Address] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: Cust1Address,dest1
```

.

Now why is the Spring not considering the `@Qualifier` annotation to find the correct bean **dest1** having qualifier `value="ForPizza"` ?

Comment: Because the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` doesn't know about the `@Qualifier` annotation. Use `<context:annotation-config />` ro if you really want to explicitly configure the parsers add a `CustomAutowireConfigurer` to enable detection of `@Qualifier`.

Comment: @Deinum, its strange bcoz i was following a tutorial in this [link](http://youtu.be/IVIhVJJGo68), and it worked there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to your Spring Configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.Shopping"/>
```

Comment: nah! same exception. Anyways i have previously added annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

Comment: after this edit, now exception has changed to `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.Shopping.Address] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: Sorry my bad, both your changes actually worked. there was a small typo in config

Answer (score 1):

Try to place `@Qualifier` on parameter rather than on method:

```
@Autowired
public void setDeliverydest(@Qualifier("ForPizza") Address deliverydest) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all annotation bean post processors and just add the below in xml.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```